# How can I get average numbers of days wind flow from 16 direction?

Tags: vectors, atmospheric-science, weather

Wind flow from North direction a nos. of days, Similarly from North East b nos. of days, East c nos. of days, South East d nos. of days, South e nos. of days, South West f nos. of days, West g nos. of days, North West h nos. of days.

Then how can I get average numbers of days wind flow from 16 directions ? 
16 directions are N,NNE, NE, NEE, E, SEE,SE, SSE,S, SSW,SW, SWW, W, NWW, NW, NNW.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126739/2451

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do (and what the problem is). Do you have data of wind flows from several days are asking how to average them over time?

Comment: I have 3 months wind flow data. But only from 8 directions. I have put 16 directions data on Rammet view to get wind rose diagram. Then how can get tentative 16 directions data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This presents the same problem as your previous question: [Determine the number of days with North-East wind direction from the number of days with North and East wind direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126739/determine-the-number-of-days-with-north-east-wind-direction-from-the-number-of-d)

If we know the wind was from the North on $a$ days and from the North-East on $b$ days then there is no way to tell how many days the wind was from the NNE. The best you could do is take data for a long time, e.g. a year, and calculate a statistical correlation between the directions. The trouble is that the climate may change from year to year, so even this wouldn't necessarily be a reliable guide.